# Angular-UI pagination missing last page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I have a table I need to do pagination and the old pager is not acceptable. So I need to use the Pagination directive. I have implemented it according to the docs and various tutorials, but it is not working for me.

I have 20 items in the array, page size is set to 7 items per page, so I should have 3 pages right? But the directive only have page 1 and 2 and 3 is missing. Please help!!

Here is the html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.isSelectedAll" ng-click="vm.checkAll()" />    
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">Customer Name</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">Customer PO#</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">Part Number</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Delivery Date</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" ng-repeat="qd in vm.qdPos | filter: query | orderBy: order | startFrom: (vm.currentPage - 1) * vm.pageSize | limitTo: vm.pageSize">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; border-top:1px solid black">
                <div class="col-xs-1"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="qd.Selected" style="vertical-align:middle"/></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">{{qd.customerName}}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">{{qd.customerPoNumber}}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">{{qd.partNumber}}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">{{qd.deliveryDate | date : 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row" style="padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:10px;">
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <a ng-click="showPoDetails(qd.id)">Details</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a ng-click="addRemark(qd.id)">Quick Remark</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1 right">Qty:</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">{{qd.quantity}}</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <span class="label" ng-class="vm.getStatusLabelColor(qd.status)">{{qd.status}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>        
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
          <uib-pagination total-items="vm.qdPos.length" 
                          item-per-page="vm.pageSize"
                          ng-model="vm.currentPage"  
                          boundary-link="true" 
                          previous-text="&lsaquo;" next-text="&rsaquo;" 
                          first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo"
                          class="pagination-sm"></uib-pagination>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app');
  var controllerId = 'app.views.purchaseOrder.qdPo';

  app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
      return input.slice(start);
    }
  });

  app.controller(controllerId, [
    '$scope', '$state', 'appSession', 
    function($scope, $state, appSession ) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.qdPos = [{
        "id": 1,
        "customerName": "Jabberbean",
        "customerPoNumber": "0591-5319",
        "partNumber": "501114818-1",
        "quantity": 782564,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-09-28T09:36:06Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "customerName": "Meembee",
        "customerPoNumber": "75997-028",
        "partNumber": "963652003-8",
        "quantity": 411521,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-08-13T20:51:47Z",
        "status": "New"
      }, {
        "id": 3,
        "customerName": "Photospace",
        "customerPoNumber": "49349-927",
        "partNumber": "295842333-6",
        "quantity": 61715,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-10-18T01:48:22Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 4,
        "customerName": "Topicstorm",
        "customerPoNumber": "16590-269",
        "partNumber": "830424508-6",
        "quantity": 831698,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-09-01T12:40:10Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 5,
        "customerName": "Jabberbean",
        "customerPoNumber": "42291-225",
        "partNumber": "550455386-5",
        "quantity": 771454,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-05-05T12:27:42Z",
        "status": "New"
      }, {
        "id": 6,
        "customerName": "Photospace",
        "customerPoNumber": "0115-5212",
        "partNumber": "682923475-1",
        "quantity": 874958,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-07-20T03:32:33Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 7,
        "customerName": "Eimbee",
        "customerPoNumber": "49738-182",
        "partNumber": "522413525-7",
        "quantity": 668127,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-06-13T18:24:09Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 8,
        "customerName": "Meembee",
        "customerPoNumber": "41250-101",
        "partNumber": "945781744-3",
        "quantity": 224937,
        "deliveryDate": "2016-02-22T07:32:15Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 9,
        "customerName": "Aivee",
        "customerPoNumber": "0591-3196",
        "partNumber": "230748890-1",
        "quantity": 648987,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-04-10T21:54:55Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 10,
        "customerName": "Jabberbean",
        "customerPoNumber": "25113-333",
        "partNumber": "082625425-X",
        "quantity": 916253,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-12-28T06:18:52Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 11,
        "customerName": "Topicstorm",
        "customerPoNumber": "59995-006",
        "partNumber": "945728924-2",
        "quantity": 810544,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-09-29T14:33:33Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 12,
        "customerName": "InnoZ",
        "customerPoNumber": "76332-002",
        "partNumber": "121586408-6",
        "quantity": 536693,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-09-11T21:10:33Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 13,
        "customerName": "InnoZ",
        "customerPoNumber": "51393-7223",
        "partNumber": "310043028-X",
        "quantity": 739695,
        "deliveryDate": "2016-02-07T10:31:12Z",
        "status": "No Change"
      }, {
        "id": 14,
        "customerName": "Blogtag",
        "customerPoNumber": "43742-0341",
        "partNumber": "637443495-1",
        "quantity": 305689,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-06-22T22:35:18Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 15,
        "customerName": "Topicstorm",
        "customerPoNumber": "53808-0680",
        "partNumber": "481012830-X",
        "quantity": 533356,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-09-27T15:40:22Z",
        "status": "New"
      }, {
        "id": 16,
        "customerName": "Meembee",
        "customerPoNumber": "54868-4811",
        "partNumber": "428331365-3",
        "quantity": 177280,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-08-08T04:52:10Z",
        "status": "New"
      }, {
        "id": 17,
        "customerName": "Meembee",
        "customerPoNumber": "62037-599",
        "partNumber": "065890821-9",
        "quantity": 17787,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-05-12T12:57:11Z",
        "status": "New"
      }, {
        "id": 18,
        "customerName": "InnoZ",
        "customerPoNumber": "45802-201",
        "partNumber": "478496364-2",
        "quantity": 689218,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-03-31T22:57:24Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 19,
        "customerName": "Photospace",
        "customerPoNumber": "65044-6586",
        "partNumber": "689861103-8",
        "quantity": 731566,
        "deliveryDate": "2015-03-16T19:25:19Z",
        "status": "Revised"
      }, {
        "id": 20,
        "customerName": "Eimbee",
        "customerPoNumber": "63187-061",
        "partNumber": "161036148-2",
        "quantity": 598961,
        "deliveryDate": "2016-02-21T07:49:44Z",
        "status": "New"
      }];

      vm.currentPage = 1;
      vm.pageSize = 7;
    }
  ]);
})();
```

Comment: please create an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I tried to create one but it is not really working. I haven't use jsfiddle before. Anyway here is the link to it https://jsfiddle.net/qwvd9hsn/2/

Comment: you need to add all the relevant scripts in External Resources

Comment: I have added angular, bootstrap and angular-ui but the jsfiddle is still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/qwvd9hsn/3/